# Drift term in rough volatility models

Tags: stochastic-volatility, numerairechange

I'm studying rough volatility papers and was wondering, why the drift term is always missing.

See for example the paper [Pricing under rough volatility](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/bayerc/files/RSVPsubmitted2.pdf) by Bayer, Friz, Gatheral.
On page 2, the fractional stochastic volatility model is introduced and the stock price process is defined by $$\frac{d S_t}{S_t} = \sigma_t d Z_t$$
Why is a drift term missing? First, I thought that it is just a simplification and it has to be incorporated in a practical application of the model. But after reading [Turbocharging Monte Carlo pricing for the rough Bergomi model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02563.pdf) by McCrickerd and Pakkanen I think it is a kind of change of numeraire since they state on page 2 that the stock price needs to have the following property $\mathbb{E}(S_t)=1, \forall t \geq 0$.

If the numeraire is changed in a way, that the stock price is equal to one in expectation, it probably has to be something like $S_t e^{-r t}$.

So, if I'm right, how do you price an option with this model? Do I have to discount the strike price as well? And what about dividends, should one discount with the risk free rate plus a continuous dividend rate?

It would be great, if someone could shed some light on this problem. If you could provide a paper, explaining this stuff, it would be great, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These papers are interested in modelling the stochastic volatility, so implicitely they model the dynamics of the forward price which has **zero drift** under the corresponding terminal measure. This makes the exposition much simpler.

It is then easy to switch back to the stock price:

- european options: an option with expiry $T$ on the stock price $S_t$ is computed as $PV_t = D_t(T) E^{Q_T}_t[\text{payoff}(S_T)] = D_t(T) E^{Q_T}_t[\text{payoff}(F_T)]$ where $F_t=E^{Q_T}_t[S_T]$, so the only thing that needs modelling is the dynamics for $F_t$ under the terminal measure $Q_T$
- non european option, volatility swaps, etc. : under the assumption that interest rates are deterministic the terminal measure and the risk neutral measure are the same, so the stochastic volatility for $F_t$ under the terminal measure is the same as the stochastic volatility for $S_t$ under the risk neutral measure.